# gnuplot interactive SVG: Toggle more that one curve

Tags: gnuplot

The SVG terminal has the option `mouse`, which allows to hide/show curves by clicking onto the corresponding entry in the key.

Now, I'm plotting my data twice. Once `with steps` and once `with points`. While the points make it more clear when a value changed, the steps make it more clear how long a value is valid. The key has only one entry for each data.

So my script looks like this:

```
plot\
    "Data1" title "first" with steps linetype 1,\
    "Data1" notitle with points linetype 1,\
    "Data2" title "second" with steps linetype 2,\
    "Data2" notitle with points linetype 2,\
    ...
```

My question is: Is there a convenient way to toggle both plots together? The only way I can think of is re-writing the javascript function which changes the visibility of the curves.

Comment: There is a keyboard shortcut to toggle all graphs visibility in some terminals, but I didn't remember what it is...

Comment: An alternative is to plot a third time with a thick white line, using the keyword front to cover the graph. Then you can toggle that line instead.

Comment: @JonatanÖström: This white line would first cover parts of other curves from other datasets, too, and the key would consist of white lines only... That's ugly.